# ¿Cómo mostrar un dato de un objeto lista de un JSON Deserealizado C#?

Tags: c#, json, windows-forms, webservice

estoy trabajando en un proyecto donde debo consumir una rest api, lo cual lo logré con la librería RESTSHARP. Esta Api la consumí utilizando método POST, enviando un JSON como parámetro y recibiendo un JSON como respuesta.
Este es el código que utilicé para consumir el webservices

```
        var client = new RestClient("www.example.cl/");
        client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("usuario", "contraseña");
        var request = new RestRequest("api/", Method.POST);
        request.AddParameter("application/json", "{\r\n  \"partida\": \"01\",\r\n  \"capitulo\": \"01\",\r\n  \"areaTransaccional\": \"001\",\r\n  \"ejercicio\": 2019,\r\n  \"folio\":" + txtFolio.Text + ",\r\n  \"usuario\":\"Usuario\"\r\n}\r\n", ParameterType.RequestBody);
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        //Creamos variable para guardar contenido del JSON
        string contenido = response.Content;
        //Deserialzamos el json
        obtenerCompromiso1 compromiso = new JsonDeserializer().Deserialize<obtenerCompromiso1>(response);
        txtDescripción.Text = compromiso.compromiso.descripcion; //Luego de ingresar un folio y apretar un botón me muestra la descripción del compromiso. quiero rescatar el monto
```

Cabe destacar que se crearon los objetos para el JSON recibido, donde logro mostrar la descripción de este ingresando un folio de un txt en un windowsform.

```
 public class Compromiso
{
    public object id { get; set; }
    public string titulo { get; set; }
    public string descripcion { get; set; }
    public Documentos documentos { get; set; }
    public string etapa { get; set; }
    public object informacionDeAjuste { get; set; }
} //Lista del tipo Documento
public class Documentos
{
    public List<Documento> documento { get; set; }
} //Aquí me gustaría poder obtener el monto del json recibido
public class Documento
{
    public string numero { get; set; }
    public int monto { get; set; }
    public string tipo { get; set; }
    public string fecha { get; set; }
    public string descripcion { get; set; }
    public int idDocumentoAjustado { get; set; }
    public TipoDeCambio tipoDeCambio { get; set; }
    public Principales principales { get; set; }
    public object imputacionesAGlosas { get; set; }
    public object camposVariables { get; set; }
}

public class TipoDeCambio
{
    public object fecha { get; set; }
    public string moneda { get; set; }
}
public class Principales
{
    public List<Principal> principal { get; set; }
}
public class Principal
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public TransaccionesPrevias transaccionesPrevias { get; set; }
    public Cumplimientos cumplimientos { get; set; }
}
public class Cumplimientos
{
    public List<Cumplimiento> cumplimiento { get; set; }
}
public class TransaccionesPrevias
{
    public List<Transaccion> transaccion { get; set; }
}
public class Transaccion
{
    public int folio { get; set; }
    public string tipo { get; set; }
    public string idCombinacion { get; set; }
    public AgrupacionesDeImputacionesACatalogos agrupacionesDeImputacionesACatalogos { get; set; }
}
public class Catalogo
{
    public string catalogo { get; set; }
    public string elemento { get; set; }
}

public class ImputacionesACatalogosDeReagrupacion
{
    public List<Catalogo> catalogo { get; set; }
}

public class Imputacion
{
    public string idConcepto { get; set; }
    public string nombreConcepto { get; set; }
    public int monto { get; set; }
    public object montoFuturo { get; set; }
    public int saldo { get; set; }
}

public class ImputacionesAConceptosPresupuestarios
{
    public List<Imputacion> imputacion { get; set; }
}

public class Agrupacion
{
    public ImputacionesACatalogosDeReagrupacion imputacionesACatalogosDeReagrupacion { get; set; }
    public ImputacionesAConceptosPresupuestarios imputacionesAConceptosPresupuestarios { get; set; }
}

public class AgrupacionesDeImputacionesACatalogos
{
    public List<Agrupacion> agrupacion { get; set; }
}

public class Cumplimiento
{
    public string fecha { get; set; }
    public int monto { get; set; }
}


public class obtenerCompromiso1
{
    public Compromiso compromiso { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string descripcion { get; set; }
    public List<object> errors { get; set; }
}
```

Dentro de los objetos hay uno que es un lista del tipo "Documento", donde en algunos JSON recibidos se ve que se pueden tener varios documentos con diferentes datos, lo que me gustaría saber es como puedo deserializar una lista del tipo documento para mostrar por ejemplo el monto de un documento. Espero puedan ayudarme, desde ya muchas gracias.
Quedo atento a sus comentarios

Comment: Prueba con esto: var documento JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Documentos>(json);

Comment: Hola Cristian, con ese codigo no puedo entrar a los demàs atributos de Documentos, solo a documento, por lo tanto no puedo mostrar el monto, muchas gracias por la respuesta. Estaba utilizando este còdigo y pasa lo mismo: `Documento doc1 = new JsonDeserializer().Deserialize<Documento>(response);`